# Why my docker image does not reflect changes made to the repository files?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I use a Dockerfile to build a docker image of my program. I have made some changes to the files and recreated the docker image, however the docker image is still using the older version of the files.   In my docker file I have a line `COPY --chown=root:root <repository directory> <repository directory>` so I do copy a current version of the repository files, nevertheless, if I make a container of the image it returns an error associated with he older version of the files.

I tried running `docker build --no-cache` without success.

The Dockerfile:

```
# "tensorflow" or "tensorflow-gpu"
ARG TENSORFLOW_TARGET="tensorflow"

# tensorflow version (deepcell 0.12.4 requires ~=2.8.0)
ARG TENSORFLOW_VERSION="2.8.4"

# "steinbock" or "steinbock-cellpose"
ARG STEINBOCK_TARGET="steinbock"

# steinbock version (for overriding setuptools-scm)
ARG STEINBOCK_VERSION

# third-party software versions
ARG FIXUID_VERSION="0.5.1"
ARG ILASTIK_BINARY="ilastik-1.3.3post3-Linux.tar.bz2"
ARG CELLPROFILER_VERSION="4.2.5"
ARG CELLPROFILER_PLUGINS_VERSION="4.2.1"
ARG CELLPOSE_VERSION="2.2"

########## TENSORFLOW ##########

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 
tensorflow/tensorflow:${TENSORFLOW_VERSION} AS tensorflow

ARG TENSORFLOW_VERSION

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" 
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE="1" PYTHONUNBUFFERED="1"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq python3 python3-pip && \
   apt-get clean && \
   python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
   python3 -m pip install "tensorflow==${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}"



########## TENSORFLOW-GPU ##########

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 
tensorflow/tensorflow:${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}-gpu as tensorflow- 
gpu

ARG TENSORFLOW_VERSION

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" 
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE="1" 
PYTHONUNBUFFERED="1"

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq python3 python3-pip && \
    apt-get clean && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install "tensorflow==${TENSORFLOW_VERSION}"



########## TENSORFLOW-MACOS ##########

# As of Jan 2023, the following hypothetical options exist for running
# tensorflow-enabled Linux images using Docker on arm64-based Macs:
#
#   1. Emulation of tensorflow/tensorflow (linux/amd64) on the client
#     - Very slow because of emulation and no vectorization/GPU support
#     - Requires a custom no-AVX wheel of tensorflow (no official wheels available)
#     - This approach has been confirmed to work with a custom no-AVX tensorflow wheel
#       from https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow-community-wheels/issues/209
#
#   2. Custom tensorflow-enabled linux image for the arm64 platform:
#     - Unclear whether this works (tensorflow for arm64-based linux is experimental)
#     - Slow multi-stage build (bazel & tensorflow require cross-compiled from source)
#
# Note that the instructions on     https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/
# are for arm64-based Mac OS only (no Linux wheels available).


########## STEINBOCK ##########

FROM ${TENSORFLOW_TARGET} AS steinbock

ARG STEINBOCK_VERSION
ARG FIXUID_VERSION
ARG ILASTIK_BINARY
ARG CELLPROFILER_VERSION
ARG CELLPROFILER_PLUGINS_VERSION
ARG TZ="Europe/Zurich"

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" 
PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE="1" PYTHONUNBUFFERED="1" 
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/tmp"

# install system packages

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq build-essential curl git locales 
python3 python3-pip python3-dev python3-venv && \
    apt-get clean && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

# set locale and timezone

RUN sed -i -e 's/# en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8/' 
/etc/locale.gen && locale-gen
ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8" LANGUAGE="en_US:en" LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
RUN ln -snf "/usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ}" /etc/localtime && echo 
"${TZ}" > /etc/timezone

# create steinbock user

RUN addgroup --gid 1000 steinbock && \
    adduser --uid 1000 --ingroup steinbock --disabled-password 
--gecos "" steinbock

# create data directory

RUN mkdir /data && \
    chown steinbock:steinbock /data

# install fixuid

ENV RUN_FIXUID=1
RUN USER=steinbock && \
    GROUP=steinbock && \
    curl -SsL "https://github.com/boxboat/fixuid/releases/download/v${FIXUID_VERSION}/fixuid-${FIXUID_VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz" | tar -C 
/usr/local/bin -xzf - && \
chmod 4755 /usr/local/bin/fixuid && \
mkdir -p /etc/fixuid
COPY --chown=root:root fixuid.yml /etc/fixuid/config.yml

# install ilastik

RUN mkdir /opt/ilastik && \
curl -SsL "https://files.ilastik.org/${ILASTIK_BINARY}" | tar -C 
/opt/ilastik -xjf - --strip-components=1

# install cellprofiler in cellprofiler-venv

RUN python3 -m venv --system-site-packages /opt/cellprofiler-venv
ENV ROOT_VENV_PATH="${PATH}" 
CELLPROFILER_VENV_PATH="/opt/cellprofiler-venv/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="${CELLPROFILER_VENV_PATH}"
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq libgtk-3-dev openjdk-11-jdk-headless 
libmysqlclient-dev libnotify-dev libsdl2-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0- 
dev && \
    apt-get clean
ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"

RUN curl -SsO https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-20.04/wxPython-4.1.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl && \
python -m pip install wxPython-4.1.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl && \
rm wxPython-4.1.0-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl

RUN python -m pip install 
git+https://github.com/CellProfiler/CellProfiler.git@4.2.x

RUN mkdir /opt/cellprofiler_plugins && \
    curl -SsL "https://github.com/BodenmillerGroup/ImcPluginsCP/archive/refs/tags/v${CELLPROFILER_PLUGINS_VERSION}.tar.gz" | tar -C /opt/cellprofiler_plugins -xzf - "ImcPluginsCP-${CELLPROFILER_PLUGINS_VERSION}/plugins/" --strip-components=2

ENV PATH="${ROOT_VENV_PATH}"

# install steinbock in steinbock-venv (including napari system 
dependencies, Jupyter Notebook/Jupyter Lab, pre-trained models)

RUN python3 -m venv --system-site-packages /opt/steinbock-venv
ENV ROOT_VENV_PATH="${PATH}" STEINBOCK_VENV_PATH="/opt/steinbock- 
venv/bin:${PATH}"
ENV PATH="${STEINBOCK_VENV_PATH}"
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yqq mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx libglib2.0-0 
libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libdbus-1-3 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxi6 
libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb- 
render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 libxcb-xfixes0 
libxcb-shape0 && \
    apt-get clean

COPY --chown=root:root steinbock /app/steinbock/steinbock/
COPY --chown=root:root requirements.txt requirements_test.txt 
conftest.py MANIFEST.in pyproject.toml setup.cfg /app/steinbock/
RUN python -m pip install -r /app/steinbock/requirements.txt && \
    python -m pip install -r /app/steinbock/requirements_test.txt 
&& \
    python -m pip install jupyter jupyterlab
ENV TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL="2" NO_AT_BRIDGE="1"

RUN --mount=source=.git,target=/app/steinbock/.git 
SETUPTOOLS_SCM_PRETEND_VERSION="${STEINBOCK_VERSION#v}" python -m 
pip install -e "/app/steinbock[imc,deepcell,napari]"

RUN mkdir -p /opt/keras/models && \
    curl -SsL https://deepcell-data.s3-us-west- 
1.amazonaws.com/saved-models/MultiplexSegmentation-9.tar.gz | tar 
-C /opt/keras/models -xzf -

# configure container

WORKDIR /data
USER steinbock:steinbock
COPY --chown=root:root entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
EXPOSE 8888
```

Build command:

```
docker build --no-cache -t 'steinbock_xti' .
```

Run command:

```
docker run -v <path to data>:/data --platform linux/amd64 -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -p 8888:8888 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v ~/.Xauthority:/home/steinbock/.Xauthority:ro -e DISPLAY=host.docker.internal:0 steinbock_xti
```

Comment: Go inside the container and check once that correct code is there and the branch is the one you need if you are using automations. And if that doesn't work prune that use 'docker system prune -a' as last resort it clears everything including other images

Comment: Show us the Dockerfile, and show us the exact command you use to build the image, and show us the exact command you use to run the container.

Comment: @ArunbhYashaswi I cannot there is an error thrown at docker run, which I am trying to fix, but the fix is not recognized

Comment: It is usual to write a docker-compose.yml file and define the desired folders as volume: https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/